# AsyncAwait Concept

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand the concept of async and await and can't quite grasp the concept of it. Up to what I've learned is in Async-await if we call a method-A and then call method-B using await from method-A then the reminder of method-A will run only after method-B's work is completed. Am I missing something? Please correct me.

If that is the case then every time we call a method even with using synchronous programming, the reminder of the method-A waits until we have finished calling method-B?

```
public void methodA(){
methodB();
Console.Writeline("MethodB has been called");
}
public void methodB(){//do stuff}
```

Now with async await:

```
public async Task methodA(){
await methodB();
Console.Writeline("MethodB has been called");
}
public async Task methodB(){//do stuff}
```

Please mind me showing the difference? I'm having really hard time trying to grasp the concept. Generally, I see posts on ThreadPool and Threads, but without having a clear concept, I don't quite get it.

Comment: What research did you do? There is tons of resources trying to explain how async/await works. Also, do you know what Task is and how it works and is used?

Comment: First, I'd suggest reading [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) to understand that *async* doesn't mean "running on another thread". Then realise that `async` and `await` are really about freeing up your current thread to go off and do something useful rather than, at some level, blocking and waiting for something asynchronous to finish.

Comment: Making it look the same is entirely the point of the async keyword.  Without it you'd have to write two methods, one that gets methodB going and another that runs after it is done.  Which can be pretty awkward, the second method cannot access any local variables of the first.  With async/await it looks far more natural.  After the compiler is done, you will in fact end up with two methods.  Parts of a hidden class, the local variables are now fields of that class.  All well hidden, you can only see it with a decompiler like ildasm.exe

Answer (score 5):

`async` and `await` are about getting threads to do *useful work* rather than sitting idly waiting for other work to complete.

If we write code that creates a new thread to do some work, and then immediately block our current thread to wait for that to finish, that's a waste. Why would we not just run the code on our current thread and have it complete useful work, and save ourselves the overhead of creating a new thread?<sup>1</sup>

So, what does `await` do? It allows our current method to *return to its caller* sooner than when all of its work is complete. That is, we're indicating that we've got no current use for the thread that we're running on, but hopefully our caller, or our callers caller, etc, does have *something else* it can be usefully running on our thread.

What if *our method* has something else it can usefully do on the current thread? Easy - decouple the *creation of an awaitable* from the `await` itself, and do that other useful work between:

```
public async Task methodA(){
  var mba = methodB();
  Console.Writeline("MethodB has been called");
  //Other useful work that doesn't depend on methodB
  var result = await mba
  //And now continue with the result from methodB
}
```

*How* `methodB` itself achieves its asynchrony is entirely an implementation detail of `methodB` - all we know is that it's arranged to complete its returned `Task` at some future point in time (this is why other languages use terms such as "futures" or "promises" where we use "task")

---

<sup>1</sup>For those wondering why this paragraph exists, it's to exactly rebut the all too common claim that `await` "creates a new thread" or similar.

Comment: Good answer, very helpful to understand the concept!

Comment: So basically, when we use await, we get the control back to the methodA(caller) immediately after the line await methodB runs, but the remainder of the methodA will run only after our work in methodB is complete?

Comment: @manisharyal - no, we return the thread to the caller *whilst* the `await` is pending. `await` has a local effect, not so large as a whole *line* of code.

Comment: @manisharyal - also, we're not guaranteed that we'll get *the same thread* back to resume our method when the wait is over, outside of particular contexts.

Answer (score 2):

> Up to what I've learned is in Async-await if we call a method-A and then call method-B using await from method-A then the reminder of method-A will run only after method-B's work is completed.

You are kind of right.

Let's take a look at a practical situation where async await would be used.

Let's say you have a Windows Forms program. On the form, there is a button. When the user presses this button, the program will fetch some stuff from the internet. After the response is received, it displays the response in a label.

Obviously, requesting stuff on the internet takes a rather long time, compared to other operations like adding stuff together, drawing a text box etc.

If you don't use async-await, the form will not respond to user interactions while the program is waiting for the response from the server. That's bad UX.

Now let's use async-await. I will use the code that you have provided:

```
public async Task methodA(){
    await methodB();
    Console.Writeline("MethodB has been called");
}
public async Task methodB(){//do stuff}
```

`methodA` is called when the button is pressed. `methodB` fetches the data. When the `await` line is reached, `methodA` returns immediately just after `methodB` is called. This way, the program execution does not need to stay in `methodA` so the form can respond to user interactions. A state machine is created to remember where the execution was in `methodA`. After `methodB` returns, execution goes back to `methodA` and execute the rest of it.

Comment: So basically, when we use await, we get the control back to the methodA(caller) immediately after the line await methodB runs, but the remainder of the methodA will run only after our work in methodB is completed?

Comment: 1. And then MSDN says there is only one thread? and where will the work in methodB will run? I read somewhere the await makes the awaited method like an interrupt or smth, but quite couldn't get it.
2. In UI/UX apps, when we await  any line on button or any controls of UI/UX, is our caller uI/ux?

Comment: @manisharyal yes there is one thread only. Imagine the computer spending some time handling the UI then switch to doing things in methodB and switching between these two tasks very quickly.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but isn't switching like you said only happens between threads in processor?

Comment: @manisharyal `Thread` here means a `Thread` object. No object is created in Async code

Comment: No. "some time handling the UI then switch to doing things in methodB and switching between these two tasks very quickly."
I meant to understand this. how switching is possible when we are running on same thread?

Comment: @manisharyal There is no `Thread` objects created so "only one thread". But it's still switching between these two tasks. And for your second question, yes the caller is some kind of UI component.